How to remove a create-react-app folder from Linux?
I would like to know how to remove the create-react-app folder which process was not completed successfully as per the error displayed was network issue; the src folder is completely empty.
In case of any resolution in order to add all folders and components src needs to have please let me know.
Thank you and have a good day.
